# gatsby-image displaying portrait images in landscape container

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I am retrieving a folder of images using GraphQL and mapping them to objects on a page to create a gallery, however I cannot seem to get `<GatsbyImage>` to 'shrink' around the portrait images and show them at the same scale as the landscape ones. The end-goal of this is to organize them in a mosaic/masonry layout, so having the portrait images show correctly and at the correct scale is crucial.

It appears that the `GatsbyImageWrapper` is stuck in landscape, and therefore will either only show a subset of the image, or will show the full image small in a landscape container when passing in `imgStyle={{ objectFit: 'CONTAIN' }}`. Please see images below, I have added white borders to demonstrate issue.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

This is what happens when I pass `imgStyle={{ objectFit: 'CONTAIN' }}` to `<GatsbyImage>`:
[image]

This is what happens when I pass no `imgStyle` attributes to `<GatsbyImage>`:
[image]

My code:

```js
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";
import React from "react";

export default function GalleryComp(props: any) {
    const data = props.query;

    return (
        <>
            <div className="mt-10">
                {data.allFile.edges.map((tile, i) => {
                return (
                <GatsbyImage image={getImage(tile.node.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData)} alt={"blah"} className="rounded-xl shadow-xl border-2 border-white" />
                )
            })}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

And here is my query:

```js
    const query = useStaticQuery(graphql`
        query galleryQuery {
            allFile(filter: { absolutePath: { regex: "/work/lx/" } }) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        childImageSharp {
                            gatsbyImageData(
                                placeholder: BLURRED
                                transformOptions: { fit: OUTSIDE }
                                width: 500
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have any problem but a misunderstanding on the properties you are dealing with: `transformOptions: { fit: OUTSIDE }` the docs:

> `outside`: Preserving aspect ratio, resize the image to be as small as
> possible while ensuring its dimensions are greater than or equal to
> both those specified.

*Source: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-resize#resize*

#### `transformOptions`

These values are passed in as an object to `transformOptions`, either as a prop to `StaticImage`, or to the resolver for dynamic images. They are advanced settings that most people will not need to change. Any provided object is merged with the defaults below.

```
| Option name | Default                   | Description                                                                                                                                                   |
| ----------- | ------------------------- | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| `grayscale` | `false`                   | Convert image to grayscale                                                                                                                                    |
| `duotone`   | `false`                   | Add duotone effect. Pass `false`, or options object containing `{highlight: string, shadow: string, opacity: number}`                                         |
| `rotate`    | `auto`                    | Rotate the image. Value in degrees.                                                                                                                           |
| `trim`      | `10`                      | Trim "boring" pixels. Value is the threshold. See [the sharp documentation](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-resize#trim).                                 |
| `cropFocus` | `"attention"`/`ATTENTION` | Controls crop behavior. See [the sharp documentation](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-resize#resize) for strategy, position and gravity.                  |
| `fit`       | `"cover"`/`COVER`         | Controls behavior when resizing an image and proving both width and height. See [the sharp documentation.](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-resize#resize) |
```

*Source: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#transformoptions*

Regarding the `imgStyle={{ objectFit: 'CONTAIN' }}`, it is also doing what it is supposed to do:

> contain
>
> The replaced content is scaled to maintain its aspect ratio
> while fitting within the element's content box. The entire object is
> made to fill the box, while preserving its aspect ratio, so the object
> will be "letterboxed" if its aspect ratio does not match the aspect
> ratio of the box.

*Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit*

It's keeping the aspect ratio while fitting the element's content box. If you don't want so, in other words. It's trying to display the image inside the container keeping the aspect ratio, and because the image is portrait (9:16 or similar) is leaving empty spaces in both sides.

That said, and without knowing the design end-goal, I think the problem is in the wrapper, not in the image itself (the one that has the border and the background). If you want the wrapper to shrink to fit the image size you must deal with it, not with the image because according to the screenshot, the border-white-wrapper has the same size as the others when it is supposed to be shrunk to fit the image size to match a masonry layout

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, and for all your help, very much appreciated. I'm definitely still getting to grips with Gatsby and GraphQL, so I'm sure there's definitely a few things I'm misunderstanding still! I found I actually managed to fix my issue by upsampling the portrait images up to 300dpi! I assume the image processing wasn't too happy with the images being 72dpi?

Comment: I think so, check how are the performance, specially in mobile devices because 300dpi is huge

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check the performance. I was just happy to have found a solution, so now can start working to optimise! :)